# word/pair list using dictionaries and strings

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, python-3.2

I am unsure how to complete this problem in python 3.x.x
Define a function wordsD that takes one parameter:
1. text, a string
text contains sentences with words separated by spaces
and ending in periods.
The function returns a dictionary of
word/sentenceList pairs, where word is each distinct
word in the text and sentenceList is the list of
sentence indices the word appear in.
Note: your code is insensitive to case lettering
for example
if text='I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."
function returns
{'i":[0,1,2],'say':[0,1],'what':[0,1],'mean':[0,1],'do':[2]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason people often ask how to do this *without* defaultdict

```
>>> text= "I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."
>>> sentences = text.lower().split('.')
>>> dic = {}
>>> for i, sen in enumerate(sentences):
...     for word in sen.split():
...         if word not in dic:         # you just need these
...             dic[word] = set()       # two extra lines
...         dic[word].add(i)
... 
>>> dic
{'i': set([0, 1, 2]), 'do': set([2]), 'say': set([0, 1]), 'what': set([0, 1]), 'mean': set([0, 1])}
```

If you really want *lists*, here is one modification to do it

```
>>> text= "I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."
>>> sentences = text.lower().split('.')
>>> dic = {}
>>> for i, sen in enumerate(sentences):
...     for word in sen.split():
...         if word not in dic:
...             dic[word] = [i]
...         elif dic[word][-1] != i:     # this prevents duplicate entries
...             dic[word].append(i)
... 
>>> dic
{'i': [0, 1, 2], 'do': [2], 'say': [0, 1], 'what': [0, 1], 'mean': [0, 1]}
```

If you're not even allowed to use enumerate

```
>>> text= "I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."
>>> sentences = text.lower().split('.')
>>> dic = {}
>>> i = -1
>>> for sen in sentences:
...     i += 1
...     for word in sen.split():
...         if word not in dic:
...             dic[word] = [i]
...         elif dic[word][-1] != i:     # this prevents duplicate entries
...             dic[word].append(i)
... 
>>> dic
{'i': [0, 1, 2], 'do': [2], 'say': [0, 1], 'what': [0, 1], 'mean': [0, 1]}
```

Comment: any possible way of handling this without enumerate?

Comment: @user2514909, sure just put `i = -1` before the loop and `i += 1` as the first line of it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> text= "I say what I mean. I mean what I say. i do."
#  convert the text to lower-case and split at `'.'` to get the sentences.
>>> sentences = text.lower().split('.')  
>>> dic = defaultdict(set)       #sets contain only unique iteme
for i,sen in enumerate(sentences): #use enumerate to get the sentence as well as index
    for word in sen.split():       #split the sentence at white-spaces to get words
        dic[word].add(i)

>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'set'>,
{'i': set([0, 1, 2]),
 'do': set([2]),
 'say': set([0, 1]),
 'what': set([0, 1]),
 'mean': set([0, 1])})
```

Using a normal dict:

```
>>> dic = {}
for i,sen in enumerate(sentences):
    for word in sen.split():
        dic.setdefault(word,set()).add(i)
...         
>>> dic
{'i': set([0, 1, 2]),
 'do': set([2]),
 'say': set([0, 1]),
 'what': set([0, 1]),
 'mean': set([0, 1])}
```

Without `enumerate`:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> index = 0
for sen in sentences:
    for word in sen.split():
        dic.setdefault(word,set()).add(index)
    index += 1
...     
>>> dic
{'i': set([0, 1, 2]), 'do': set([2]), 'say': set([0, 1]), 'what': set([0, 1]), 'mean': set([0, 1])}
```

Comment: I think it's ok to just call `.lower()` on text at the beginning

Comment: @gnibbler good point, fixed it.

Comment: is there a way to do this without enumerate?

Comment: @user2514909 you've to use a manual counter then.